# Remove hex escape from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following hex as a string: `"\xfe\xff"`. I'd like to convert this to `"feff"`. How do I do this?

The closest I got was `"\xfe\xff".inspect.gsub("\\x", "")`, which returns `"\"FEFF\""`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"\xfe\xff".unpack("H*").first
# => "feff"
```

Comment: How would you do this in reverse?

Comment: @MartinVelez: `"\xfe\xff".unpack("H*").pack("H*")`

Answer (score 5):

You are dealing with what's called an escape sequence in your double quoted string. The most common escape sequence in a double quoted string is "\n", but ruby allows you to use other escape sequences in strings too. Your string, "\xfe\xff", contains two hex escape sequences, which are of the form:

```
\xNN
```

Escape sequences represent ONE character. When ruby processes the string, it notices the "\" and converts the whole hex escape sequence to one character. After ruby processes the string, there is no \x left anywhere in the string. Therefore, looking for a \x in the string is fruitless--it doesn't exist. The same is true for the characters 'f' and 'e' found in your escape sequences: they do not exist in the string after ruby processes the string.

Note that ruby processes hex escape sequences in double quoted strings only, so the type of string--double or single quoted--is entirely relevant. In a single quoted string, the series of characters '\xfe' is four characters long because there is no such thing as a hex escape sequence in a single quoted string:

```
str = "\xfe"
puts str.length    #=>1

str = '\xfe'
puts str.length    #=>4
```

Regexes behave like double quoted strings, so it is possible to use an entire escape sequence in a regex:

```
/\xfe/
```

When ruby processes the regex, then just like with a double quoted string, ruby converts the hex escape sequence to a single character. That allows you to search for the single character in a string containing the same hex escape sequence:

```
if "abc\xfe" =~ /\xfe/
```

If you pretend for a minute that the character ruby converts the escape sequence "\xfe" to is the character 'z', then that if statement is equivalent to:

```
if "abcz" =~ /z/
```

It's important to realize that the regex is not searching the string for a '\' followed by an 'x' followed by an 'f' followed by an 'e'. Those characters do not exist in the string.

The inspect() method allows you to see the escape sequences in a string by nullifying the escape sequences, like this:

```
str = "\\xfe\\xff"
puts str

--output:--
\xfe\xff
```

In a double quoted string, `"\\"` represents a literal backslash, while an escape sequence begins with only one slash.

Once you've nullified the escape sequences, then you can match the literal characters, like the two character sequence '\x'. But it's easier to just pick out the parts you want rather than matching the parts you don't want:

```
str = "\xfe\xff"
str = str.inspect   #=> "\"\\xFE\\xFF\""

result = ""

str.scan /x(..)/ do |groups_arr|
  result << groups_arr[0]
end

puts result.downcase

--output:--
feff
```

Here it is with gsub:

```
str = "\xfe\xff"
str = str.inspect  #=>"\"\\xFE\\xFF\""

str.gsub!(/
  "?      #An optional quote mark
  \\      #A literal '\' 
   x      #An 'x'
  (..)    #Any two characters, captured in group 1
  "?      #An optional quote mark
/xm) do 
  Regexp.last_match(1)  
end

puts str.downcase

--output:--
feff
```

Remember, a regex acts like a double quoted string, so to specify a literal \ in a regex, you have to write `\\`. However, in a regex you don't have to worry about a `"` being mistaken for the end of the regex, so you don't need to escape it, like you do in a double quoted string.

Just for fun:

```
str = "\xfe\xff"

result = ""

str.each_byte do |int_code|
  result << sprintf('%x', int_code)
end

p result


--output:--
"feff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling inspect?  That's adding the extra quotes..

Also, putting that in double quotes means the \x is interpolated.  Put it in single quotes and everything should be good.

```
'\xfe\xff'.gsub("\\x","")
 => "feff"
```

Comment: "\xfe\xff".gsub("\\x", "") returns "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Comment: fixed.  double quotes means the \x is interpolated

Comment: In the question the string is double quote string `"\xfe\xff"`, not `'\xfe\xff'`

Comment: @YuHao is the string literally `"\xfe\xff"`?  If so, just add double quotes in the string and it still works.

Comment: My answer is correct either way.  Either the string is `\xfe\xff` or it's `"\xfe\xff"` -- you just don't put the string literal in double quotes in your code -- that's what messes up the regex.  This is irregardless of what the string actually is.

Comment: _irregardless_??  Is that the opposite of regardless? I.e. it's entirely relevant?  If so, then you are correct because the type if string--single or double quoted--makes all the difference in the world.  _you just don't put the string literal in double quotes in your code_ Huh?  `str = "hello"`  The op's string is a double quoted string, and you've changed it to a single quoted string, which completely changes the meaning of the string.  For instance, take the length of the double quoted string and compare it to the length of the single quoted string.  What explains the difference?

Comment: _Put it in single quotes and everything should be good._  Did you ever consider that the op is getting the string from outside the program?   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: _you just don't put the string literal in double quotes in your code_, Heck, just write `str = "feff"` in the code, and be done with it.

Comment: @7stud you seem to have anger issues.  Please try to be productive with actual suggestions if you have problems with an answer.  The question was unclear.  When you say you have a string of "foo", does that mean you have a string containing 5 characters `"foo"` or does it contain 3?  If it contains 3, then saying 'foo' is the same as "foo".

Comment: @7stud the question states: `I have the following hex as a string: "\xfe\xff"`.  Obviously a " symbol is not valid hex.  From that, I believe he has a string object that contains the following 8 characters: `\xfe\xff`  Without any quotes.  While he is testing, he is putting those characters in a string literal using double quotes.  I believe this is causing confusion by interpolating the \x and subsequent hex instead of representing it as two characters.  That is the question I answered.  That may not be what was intended, but I believe it to be a valid interpretation of the question.